# How could amounts of data / aggregated data be stored the best?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, large-data

How could large amounts of data / aggregated data be stored the best? Or to cache? Do you have recommendations?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to do with the data?

Comment: I would like to analyze and visualize them in form of dynamic diagrames

Comment: Then you need to look for the tools which use database data for example draw charts, etc. - _BI Reporting tools_.

Comment: Okay thank you very much but do you have also a recommendation how I could store large data preferably?

Comment: Data captured from an application _or_ generated from a process is generally stored in a database for further usage (for querying, reporting, charting, etc). There are many database programs - broadly categorized as SQL and NoSQL databases. Examples: MongoDB is a kind of NoSQL database. MySQL is a SQL/Relational database.

Comment: What do you mean by "large amount of data"?